# Laravel4 Bad Method Call of library class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to call

```
$log =  Log::render();
```

but all i get is

```
BadMethodCallException: Method [render] does not exist.
```

I've got a Log.php in my /app/libraries directory with the method render.
Right before calling the render method of Log I call the render method of a Class called Map.
It's the same thing, but the Log does not work.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure it is looking within Laravel's [`Log`](http://four.laravel.com/docs/errors#logging) class for the method `render` which is causing the error (since that method doesn't exist).

You should either namespace your class under something different, or remove the namespace alias within `app/config/app.php` for Laravel's Log.

Comment: Thank you. I named my libray class Render and named the methods Map and Log ;)

Answer (score 1):

Laravel comes with its own [Log](http://four.laravel.com/docs/errors#logging) class, which is likely being picked up and used before your log class.  Try [namespacing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) your Log class and then reference the namespaced class instead.